# Проверка текста для отправки в БД

Tags: php, mysql

Проблема в том, что при получении текста с БД я получаю экраннированные кавычки

```
       /"Привет/"
```

При отправки в БД, переменная проходит функции

```
    $message = htmlspecialchars($message);
    $message = nl2br($message);
    $message = mysql_real_escape_string($message);
```

В БД лежит вот так

```
    \&quot;Привет\&quot;
```

Как сдела так, чтобы кавычки при выводе из БД были не экранированы ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$message = str_replace('/"','"',$message);